# Oracle ADF openPopUp with PageFragments

Tags: popup, oracle-adf, page-fragments

I have a popup that was opened when a query was performed. I had a bean that processed the query and then opened my popup.

The problem is that I now changed my page from .jsf to .jsff(Fragments), and it is no longer working.

Can anyone explain me how to solve this problem?

This is my Bean Class:

```
package view;

import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.el.MethodExpression;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent;

import oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.RichPopup;
import oracle.adf.view.rich.event.QueryEvent;

import org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.ExtendedRenderKitService;
import org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.util.Service;

public class newBean {

    public newBean() {
        super();
    }

    public void processSomeQuery(QueryEvent queryEvent) {   

     /** Manipulate ViewCriteria, if you want and 
      *  then invoke query,optionally 
      */   
     System.out.println("INNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN");   
         invokeQueryEventMethodExpression("#{bindings.ImplicitViewCriteriaQuery.processQuery}",   
            queryEvent);   

     openPopup("p1");
     }   
     /**
      * Gets ViewCriteria used by the QueryModel
      */     

     private void invokeQueryEventMethodExpression(String expression,   
                  QueryEvent queryEvent) {   

     FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();   
     ELContext elctx = fctx.getELContext();   
     ExpressionFactory efactory =   
      fctx.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();   
     MethodExpression me =   
      efactory.createMethodExpression(elctx, expression, Object.class,   
                new Class[] { QueryEvent.class });   
     me.invoke(elctx, new Object[] { queryEvent });  
     } 

    public void openPopup (String popupId) {
        ExtendedRenderKitService erkService =
        Service.getService(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRenderKit(),
        ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
        erkService.addScript(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),
        "var hints = {autodismissNever:true}; " +
        "AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent('" + popupId +
        "').show(hints);");
        System.out.println("POPUP INNNNN");
    }

    public void closePopup (String popupId) {
        ExtendedRenderKitService erkService =
        Service.getService(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRenderKit(),
        ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
        erkService.addScript(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),
        "var hints = {autodismissNever:true}; " +
        "AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent('" + popupId +
        "').hide(hints);");
    }

}
```

This is my popup Code which has a table inside to show results from a query:

```
<af:panelGroupLayout layout="vertical" id="pgl2">
                    <af:popup childCreation="deferred" autoCancel="disabled" id="p1" contentDelivery="lazyUncached">
                        <af:panelWindow id="pw1">
                            <af:panelCollection id="pc1">
                                <f:facet name="menus"/>
                                <f:facet name="toolbar"/>
                                <f:facet name="statusbar"/>
                                <af:table value="#{bindings.NameView1_1.collectionModel}" var="row"
                                          rows="#{bindings.NameView1_1.rangeSize}"
                                          emptyText="#{bindings.NameView1_1.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
                                          rowBandingInterval="0"
                                          selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.NameView1_1.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
                                          selectionListener="#{bindings.NameView1_1.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
                                          rowSelection="single" fetchSize="#{bindings.NameView1_1.rangeSize}"
                                          id="resId1">
                                    <af:column headerText="#{bindings.NameView1_1.hints.IdNo.label}" id="resId1c1">
                                        <af:outputText value="#{row.IdNo}"
                                                       shortDesc="#{bindings.NameView1_1.hints.IdNo.tooltip}" id="ot1">
                                            <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false"
                                                              pattern="#{bindings.NameView1_1.hints.IdNo.format}"/>
                                        </af:outputText>
                                    </af:column>
                                    <af:column headerText="#{bindings.NameView1_1.hints.Title.label}" id="resId1c2">
                                        <af:outputText value="#{row.Title}"
                                                       shortDesc="#{bindings.NameView1_1.hints.Title.tooltip}"
                                                       id="ot2"/>
                                    </af:column>
                                    <af:column headerText="#{bindings.NameView1_1.hints.Name.label}" id="resId1c3">
                                        <af:outputText value="#{row.Name}"
                                                       shortDesc="#{bindings.NameView1_1.hints.Name.tooltip}" id="ot3"/>
                                    </af:column>
                                    <af:column headerText="#{bindings.NameView1_1.hints.Rowid1.label}" id="resId1c28">
                                        <af:outputText value="#{row.Rowid1}"
                                                       shortDesc="#{bindings.NameView1_1.hints.Rowid1.tooltip}"
                                                       id="ot28"/>
                                    </af:column>
                                </af:table>
                            </af:panelCollection>
                        </af:panelWindow>
                    </af:popup>
```

PS: To not had very extensive code for the table I deleted to post here some of the table values, hope I did not made mistake.

Also on the query I defined the QueryListner to be: #{managedBean1.processSomeQuery}

Thanks you so much.
Best Regards

Comment: How do you run your jsff then?

Comment: I have an Unbounded TaskFlow which has a jsf page. Then I have a bounded taskFlow which has a jsff page which performs a query and should present the results of that query on a table(PopUP).

Comment: Are you sure the popup id is still: "p1"? You can check the ID generated using some developer tool in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use PopupId directly, create binding for your popup in your newBean Class and use this binding and method getClientId();

for instance, change the newBean and add the following inside of the top of the class

```
private RichPopup myPopup=new RichPopup();
public RichPopup getMyPopup(){ return this.myPopup; }
public void setMyPopup(RichPopup myPopup) { this.myPopup = myPopup; }
```

Then change the code inside openPopup function so that:

```
        erkService.addScript(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),
    "var hints = {autodismissNever:true}; " +
    "AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent('" + popupId +
    "').show(hints);");
    System.out.println("POPUP INNNNN");
```

get replaced by

```
    myPopup.show(hints);
    System.out.println("POPUP INNNNN");
```

Don't forget to bind your popup inside the jsff like the following:

```
<af:popup childCreation="deferred" autoCancel="disabled" id="p1" contentDelivery="lazyUncached" bindings="#{pageFlowScope.newBean.myPopup}">
```

Comment: Actually, if you got binding to popup, why don't you use it directly? Like getMyPopup().show(hints) ?

Comment: Well, actually whole answer is plain wrong thing to do. Refer to documentation, complete sample provided: http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_popup.html

Comment: @Nagh I changed the function to show popup using the popup show function, but I'd appreciate you not being offensive when you say that my answer is PLAIN WRONG!

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be offensive. However, why you insist on initializing private property that hold binding for popup on declaration? Thats ain't necessary, since it will be initialized by component itself but will also lead to hard debug session when component will fail to initialize property itself. I've been lazy and didn't write how to init hints >.< However, I've been nice to provide link with a cool example. So just lets refine this answer and make it perfect solution ^_-

Comment: One more tip regarding component bindings here: https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/scope_object_serialization_failed_object . Its not necessary to do it while your bean in request scope or lower. But I think its a good practice to use it anyway and keep bean serializable. Or it will become real headache, with memory on production escpecially when scope wider then request.

Comment: @Nagh I absolutely agree with you about creating bindings for component in Managed Beans, specially about clustering and serialization.
The point here is that I'm not sure about the structure of page and task flows from the person who ask the question to determine the the popup id, also as you say if it's request or view scopes its okay, and still it is mentioned in a couple of articles in Oracle Blogs, so it's not that bad practice!